# Obtener nombre de columna mysql

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla en mysql generada por medio de un stored procedure, necesitaba que la tabla me mostrara algunas filas en columna y eso ya lo logré, pero ahora no sé cómo guardar el nombre de dichas columnas para poder trabajar con esos datos desde una aplicación en android, leí que accediendo al esquema se logra, pero no sé en qué parte del sp ponerlo.

Les dejo el código de mi sp:

```
 CREATE DEFINER=`consultax`@`%` PROCEDURE `TALLAS_COLUMNS`(pv_cve_modelo char(6))
BEGIN
SET group_concat_max_len=5000;
SET @sql = NULL;
SET @pv_cve_modelo = pv_cve_modelo;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
                'IF(COR.PUNTO01 = ''',
                COR.PUNTO01,
                ''', EXI.EXI01, NULL) AS ',
                CONCAT("'",COR.PUNTO01,"'")
                ), 
    CONCAT(
                ' ,IF(COR.PUNTO02 = ''',
                COR.PUNTO02,
                ''', EXI.EXI02, NULL) AS ',
                CONCAT("'",COR.PUNTO02,"'")
                ),
    CONCAT(
                ' ,IF(COR.PUNTO03 = ''',
                COR.PUNTO03,
                ''', EXI.EXI03, NULL) AS ',
                CONCAT("'",COR.PUNTO03,"'")
                ),
    CONCAT(
                ' ,IF(COR.PUNTO04 = ''',
                COR.PUNTO04,
                ''', EXI.EXI04, NULL) AS ',
                CONCAT("'",COR.PUNTO04,"'")
                ),
    CONCAT(
                ' ,IF(COR.PUNTO05 = ''',
                COR.PUNTO05,
                ''', EXI.EXI05, NULL) AS ',
                CONCAT("'",COR.PUNTO05,"'")
                ),
    CONCAT(
                ' ,IF(COR.PUNTO06 = ''',
                COR.PUNTO06,
                ''', EXI.EXI06, NULL) AS ',
                CONCAT("'",COR.PUNTO06,"'")
                ),
    CONCAT(
                ' ,IF(COR.PUNTO07 = ''',
                COR.PUNTO07,
                ''', EXI.EXI07, NULL) AS ',
                CONCAT("'",COR.PUNTO07,"'")
                ),
    CONCAT(
                ' ,IF(COR.PUNTO08 = ''',
                COR.PUNTO08,
                ''', EXI.EXI08, NULL) AS ',
                CONCAT("'",COR.PUNTO08,"'")
                ),
    CONCAT(
                ' ,IF(COR.PUNTO09 = ''',
                COR.PUNTO09,
                ''', EXI.EXI09, NULL) AS ',
                CONCAT("'",COR.PUNTO09,"'")
                ),
    CONCAT(
                ' ,IF(COR.PUNTO10 = ''',
                COR.PUNTO10,
                ''', EXI.EXI10, NULL) AS ',
                CONCAT("'",COR.PUNTO10,"'")
                ),
    CONCAT(
                ' ,IF(COR.PUNTO11 = ''',
                COR.PUNTO11,
                ''', EXI.EXI11, NULL) AS ',
                CONCAT("'",COR.PUNTO11,"'")
                ),
    CONCAT(
                ' ,IF(COR.PUNTO12 = ''',
                COR.PUNTO12,
                ''', EXI.EXI12, NULL) AS ',
                CONCAT("'",COR.PUNTO12,"'")
                ),
    CONCAT(
                ' ,IF(COR.PUNTO13 = ''',
                COR.PUNTO13,
                ''', EXI.EXI13, NULL) AS ',
                CONCAT("'",COR.PUNTO13,"'")
                ),
    CONCAT(
                ' ,IF(COR.PUNTO14 = ''',
                COR.PUNTO14,
                ''', EXI.EXI14, NULL) AS ',
                CONCAT("'",COR.PUNTO14,"'")
                ),
    CONCAT(
                ' ,IF(COR.PUNTO15 = ''',
                COR.PUNTO15,
                ''', EXI.EXI15, NULL) AS ',
                CONCAT("'",COR.PUNTO15,"'")
                ),
    CONCAT(
                ' ,IF(COR.PUNTO16 = ''',
                COR.PUNTO16,
                ''', EXI.EXI16, NULL) AS ',
                CONCAT("'",COR.PUNTO16,"'")
                ),
    CONCAT(
                ' ,IF(COR.PUNTO17 = ''',
                COR.PUNTO17,
                ''', EXI.EXI17, NULL) AS ',
                CONCAT("'",COR.PUNTO17,"'")
                ),
    CONCAT(
                ' ,IF(COR.PUNTO18 = ''',
                COR.PUNTO18,
                ''', EXI.EXI18, NULL) AS ',
                CONCAT("'",COR.PUNTO18,"'")
                ),
    CONCAT(
                ' ,IF(COR.PUNTO19 = ''',
                COR.PUNTO19,
                ''', EXI.EXI19, NULL) AS ',
                CONCAT("'",COR.PUNTO19,"'")
                ),
    CONCAT(
                ' ,IF(COR.PUNTO20 = ''',
                COR.PUNTO20,
                ''', EXI.EXI20, NULL) AS ',
                CONCAT("'",COR.PUNTO20,"'")
                ),
    CONCAT(
                ' ,IF(COR.PUNTO21 = ''',
                COR.PUNTO21,
                ''', EXI.EXI21, NULL) AS ',
                CONCAT("'",COR.PUNTO21,"'")
                ),
    CONCAT(
                ' ,IF(COR.PUNTO22 = ''',
                COR.PUNTO22,
                ''', EXI.EXI22, NULL) AS ',
                CONCAT("'",COR.PUNTO22,"'")
                ),
    CONCAT(
                ' ,IF(COR.PUNTO23 = ''',
                COR.PUNTO23,
                ''', EXI.EXI23, NULL) AS ',
                CONCAT("'",COR.PUNTO23,"'")
                ),
    CONCAT(
                ' ,IF(COR.PUNTO24 = ''',
                COR.PUNTO24,
                ''', EXI.EXI24, NULL) AS ',
                CONCAT("'",COR.PUNTO24,"'")
                ),
    CONCAT(
                ' ,IF(COR.PUNTO25 = ''',
                COR.PUNTO25,
                ''', EXI.EXI25, NULL) AS ',
                CONCAT("'",COR.PUNTO25,"'")
                ),
    CONCAT(
                ' ,IF(COR.PUNTO26 = ''',
                COR.PUNTO26,
                ''', EXI.EXI26, NULL) AS ',
                CONCAT("'",COR.PUNTO26,"'")
                ),
    CONCAT(
                ' ,IF(COR.PUNTO27 = ''',
                COR.PUNTO27,
                ''', EXI.EXI27, NULL) AS ',
                CONCAT("'",COR.PUNTO27,"'")
                ),
    CONCAT(
                ' ,IF(COR.PUNTO28 = ''',
                COR.PUNTO28,
                ''', EXI.EXI28, NULL) AS ',
                CONCAT("'",COR.PUNTO28,"'")
                ),
    CONCAT(
                ' ,IF(COR.PUNTO29 = ''',
                COR.PUNTO29,
                ''', EXI.EXI29, NULL) AS ',
                CONCAT("'",COR.PUNTO29,"'")
                ),
    CONCAT(
                ' ,IF(COR.PUNTO30 = ''',
                COR.PUNTO30,
                ''', EXI.EXI30, NULL) AS ',
                CONCAT("'",COR.PUNTO30,"'")
                )

  )

  INTO @sql
FROM PRODUCTO PRD
  INNER JOIN EXIPRO EXI  ON EXI.PRODUCTO = PRD.CLAVE
  INNER JOIN CORRIDA COR ON COR.LLAVE = PRD.CORRIDA
AND (COR.PUNTO01 != "" 
    OR COR.PUNTO02 != "" 
    OR COR.PUNTO03 != "" 
    OR COR.PUNTO04 != "" 
    OR COR.PUNTO05 != "" 
    OR COR.PUNTO06 IS NOT NULL 
    OR COR.PUNTO07 IS NOT NULL 
    OR COR.PUNTO08 IS NOT NULL 
    OR COR.PUNTO09 IS NOT NULL 
    OR COR.PUNTO10 IS NOT NULL
    OR COR.PUNTO11 IS NOT NULL
    OR COR.PUNTO12 IS NOT NULL
    OR COR.PUNTO13 IS NOT NULL
    OR COR.PUNTO14 IS NOT NULL
    OR COR.PUNTO15 IS NOT NULL
    OR COR.PUNTO16 IS NOT NULL
    OR COR.PUNTO17 IS NOT NULL
    OR COR.PUNTO18 IS NOT NULL
    OR COR.PUNTO19 IS NOT NULL
    OR COR.PUNTO20 IS NOT NULL
    OR COR.PUNTO21 IS NOT NULL
    OR COR.PUNTO22 IS NOT NULL
    OR COR.PUNTO23 IS NOT NULL
    OR COR.PUNTO24 IS NOT NULL
    OR COR.PUNTO25 IS NOT NULL
    OR COR.PUNTO26 IS NOT NULL
    OR COR.PUNTO27 IS NOT NULL
    OR COR.PUNTO28 IS NOT NULL
    OR COR.PUNTO29 IS NOT NULL
    OR COR.PUNTO30 IS NOT NULL)
WHERE PRD.MODELO = @pv_cve_modelo;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT EXI.TIENDA, 
                            PRD.CLAVE AS PRODUCTO, 
                            PRD.NOMBRE, 
                            ', @sql, 
                                                                 '             
                    FROM PRODUCTO PRD
                        INNER JOIN EXIPRO  EXI ON EXI.PRODUCTO = PRD.CLAVE
                        INNER JOIN CORRIDA COR ON COR.LLAVE = PRD.CORRIDA 
                        AND (COR.PUNTO01 != "" 
                                OR COR.PUNTO02 != "" 
                                OR COR.PUNTO03 != "" 
                                OR COR.PUNTO04 != "" 
                                OR COR.PUNTO05 != "" 
                                OR COR.PUNTO06 IS NOT NULL 
                                OR COR.PUNTO07 IS NOT NULL 
                                OR COR.PUNTO08 IS NOT NULL 
                                OR COR.PUNTO09 IS NOT NULL 
                                OR COR.PUNTO10 IS NOT NULL
                                OR COR.PUNTO11 IS NOT NULL)
                        WHERE PRD.MODELO = ''',  @pv_cve_modelo ,''' 
                   ORDER BY 1, 2, 3');

                                                                  -- AND (COR.PUNTO01 != '''' OR COR.PUNTO02 != '''' OR COR.PUNTO03 != '''' OR COR.PUNTO04 != '''' OR COR.PUNTO05 != '''' OR 
                                                                  -- COR.PUNTO06 != '''' OR COR.PUNTO07 != '''' OR COR.PUNTO08 != '''' OR COR.PUNTO09 != '''' OR COR.PUNTO10 != ''''
                   -- AND (COR.PUNTO01 != '''' OR COR.PUNTO02 != '''')
  -- SELECT @SQL;

  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

/*Nota: Trae aun detalle el de contemplar cada columna de talla(en el select agregar CONCAT(
                ' ,IF(COR.PUNTO(No. Columna) = ''',
                COR.PUNTO((No. Columna)),
                ''', EXI.EXI(No. Columna), NULL) AS ',
                CONCAT("'",COR.PUNTO(No. Columna),"'")
                )

En where agregar OR COR.PUNTO(No. Columna) IS NOT NULL
)*/

END
```

(El sp lo utilizo primero en un servicio web wcf)
 Y esta es la tabla que me regresa el store procdure, necesito extraer los valores de las columnas:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Añadiendo `AS [NombreColumna]` por cada valor que tengas definido.

Comment: Aunque mis columnas sean dinámicas, es que hace una búsqueda por producto y me regresa una tabla con tallas y cantidad, pero las tallas son distintas por cada producto.

Comment: @Sandra No veo ningún `create table` en tu procedimiento. Hasta donde puedo ver, este procedimiento ejecuta un `SELECT` y ya. Si quieres guardar estos datos, te recomiendo agregues `create table algunaTabla` al inicio de la sentencia SQL para que el resultado sea enviado a alguna tabla.

Comment: Puedes indicar que libreria o framework utilizas para conectarte a la base de datos. Si puedes colocar un extracto del código, mejor.

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que quieres simplemente es conocer el nombre de las columnas de una tabla (no se si te entendi bien. Tienes las siguientes posibilidades. Para el caso de una hipotetica tabla Articulos:

```
mysql> desc Articulo;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| creado     | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| modificado | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| titulo     | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| resumen    | longtext     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| texto      | longtext     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| pclave     | longtext     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| publicado  | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| slug       | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
9 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

o bien:

```
mysql> show columns from Articulo;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| creado     | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| modificado | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| titulo     | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| resumen    | longtext     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| texto      | longtext     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| pclave     | longtext     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| publicado  | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| slug       | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
9 rows in set (0,01 sec)
```

O si solo quieres saber los nombres:

```
mysql> select COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = 'Articulo';
+-------------+
| COLUMN_NAME |
+-------------+
| id          |
| creado      |
| modificado  |
| titulo      |
| resumen     |
| texto       |
| pclave      |
| publicado   |
| slug        |
+-------------+
9 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

Comment: Quiero saber el nombre de las columnas con la tabla que me regresa el select de mi stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Como te dije en mi comentario, no estás enviando el resultado de tu consulta a ninguna tabla, por lo que es casi imposible obtener el nombre de las columnas (a menos que los definas tú misma al momento de crear la tabla).

Como alternativa, podrías usar esto:

```
set @sql = concat("create table miTabla ", "select ext.tienda, ", @sql , ...)
```

Y después podrías usar lo indicado en la [respuesta de Ricardo Fernandez](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/22295/obtener-nombre-de-columna-mysql/22321#22321), o bien hacer una consulta a la base de datos `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`:

```
select *
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'BaseDeDatos'
  and TABLE_NAME = 'miTabla'
  -- Agrega otros criterios (por ejemplo, los campos que no quieres mostrar)
;
```

Esto te dará un resultado con las siguientes columnas:

```
+---------------+-------------------+------------------+----------------------+------------------+----------------+-------------+-----------+--------------------------+------------------------+-------------------+---------------+--------------------+-------------------+------------------+------------+----------------+---------------------------------+----------------+
| TABLE_CATALOG | TABLE_SCHEMA      | TABLE_NAME       | COLUMN_NAME          | ORDINAL_POSITION | COLUMN_DEFAULT | IS_NULLABLE | DATA_TYPE | CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH | CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH | NUMERIC_PRECISION | NUMERIC_SCALE | CHARACTER_SET_NAME | COLLATION_NAME    | COLUMN_TYPE      | COLUMN_KEY | EXTRA          | PRIVILEGES                      | COLUMN_COMMENT |
+---------------+-------------------+------------------+----------------------+------------------+----------------+-------------+-----------+--------------------------+------------------------+-------------------+---------------+--------------------+-------------------+------------------+------------+----------------+---------------------------------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

lo que se requiere es que se muestren los nombres de las columnas en una consulta multitabla, hasta ahora solo han proporcionado soluciones alternas que solo se basan en una sola tabla como son SHOW, DESC o COLUMN_NAME cuando en realidad se necesita lo siguiente:

SELECT nombre_escuela, id_alumno, fecha_pago, nivel_academico FROM Tescuela, Talumnos, Tpagos WHERE id_alumno =  id_escuela AND fecha_pago = id_alumno

esta consulta es multitabla y se requeririan los nombres de los campos en automatico, se que diran, ya los escribiste, ¿para que los quieres? pero y si lo que se mandan son diferentes querys???

los nombres se requeririan para ponerlos en automatico como cabecera de tabla y los registros como datos, para generar una tabla dinamica

Comment: Primero que nada, esto no es un foro! Lo que has puesto debería ser una respuesta, y no una *"queja"*. Si quieres responder a la pregunta hazlo, pero en ese caso lo que escribes debe responder a la pregunta. Te recomiendo leer [ask] y hacer el [tour] para empezar a entender cómo funciona SO. Un saludo y bienvenido :)